# compare two text file and find common timestamp

Tags: python, text, timestamp

I have two text files. Both are like below with lots of raws:

```
2014-09-06 12:18:29  0 7Z
2014-09-06 21:00:41  0 7Z
2014-09-06 02:28:06  0 7Z
2014-09-06 13:06:53  0 7Z
```

I want to compare these two file and make a new file of second column where this second column is similar in both files. But the point is second column is a timestamp, and I want to count columns in two files when they are similar or they have max 5 second difference. For example for the first raw in my example above, this raw will be count as similar if in another file we have the second column in this range: "12:18:29 to 12:18:34".

What I have for reading the first file is this:

```
f= open ('green.txt','r')
f= open ('red.txt','r')
with open ('common', 'w') as h:
    for line in f:
        elements = line.split (' ')
        data = elements [1]
```

But because I want to compare timestamp I do not know how to do this. In my code data will be string.

Comment: Don't parse the file on your own - try using pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html Then also data manipulation will be way easier.

Comment: Read about [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and section [Supported operations:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure this out and here we go.

1. So basically what I did is open both the files and then stored all the lines from the first file to a list so we can compare it to the lines in the second file.
2. I used the **datetime** library to extract the timestamp (using datetime.strptime() with an exception handling which is needed as the timestamp is **trailed by some text**)
3. Then obtained the absolute difference between two **datetime** objects used it as a condition and wherever the difference is <=5seconds then we write it in the third file.

I made some changes in the text file to illustrate the output

green.txt

```
2014-09-06 12:18:29  0 7Z
2014-09-06 21:00:41  0 7Z
2014-09-06 02:28:06  0 7Z
2014-09-06 13:06:53  0 7Z
```

red.txt

```
2014-09-06 12:18:25  0 7Z
2014-09-06 21:00:50  0 7Z
2014-09-06 02:28:23  0 7Z
2014-09-06 13:06:58  0 7Z
```

The output will be file 'common.txt'

```
12:18:29
13:06:53
```

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

f1= open ('green.txt','r')
f2= open ('red.txt','r')
f3=open('common.txt','w')


fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  #timestamp format


def parse_datetime(line,fmt):                #this really important function is used to parse timestamp with date from a string
    try:
        t = datetime.strptime(line, fmt)
    except ValueError as v:
        if len(v.args) > 0 and v.args[0].startswith('unconverted data remains: '):
            line = line[:-(len(v.args[0]) - 26)]
            t = datetime.strptime(line, fmt)
        else:
            raise
    return t


times1 = []

for linef1 in f1:           #this part stores lines from green.txt to a list 
    times1.append(parse_datetime(linef1,fmt))  

for linef2 in f2:
    t2 = parse_datetime(linef2,fmt)   

    for t1 in times1:               #this loop compares the first file with the second
        diff= abs(t1-t2)            #  finding the time difference
        if diff.seconds <=5:        # condition check if the difference is less than 5 seconds
            f3.write(t1.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+'\n')


f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```